# How to get phpize for a certain PHP version?

Tags: php

If I run `phpize -v` then I get

```
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20170718
Zend Module Api No:      20170718
Zend Extension Api No:   320170718
```

If I open phpinfo then it shows a newer date

[image]

so my phpize is outdated.

---

This is the output of `php -v`:

```
PHP 7.4.21 (cli) (built: Jul  1 2021 16:09:41) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.21, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

If I create a php info page and show it, then it shows **PHP Version 7.4.21** too

How can I get phpize for php 7.4 ?

Comment: From what you posted, it looks like you have multiple versions of PHP.  The PHP on the `cli` is a different version than what you have running under your web server.  You should be able to find the correct version of `phpize` was installed with the different version of PHP, but you have not described how PHP was installed so I am unable to point you to where it would be.

Comment: No, if I run `php -v` then I get `PHP 7.4.21`, if I open a phpinfo site then I get `PHP 7.4.21` too, see my updated question please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.

First I searched for php7:

```
apt-cache search php7.4
```

then I found **php7.4-dev** and installed it:

```
sudo apt install php7.4-dev
```

This installed `phpize7.4` in **/usr/bin**

The last step is to set phpize to the new version with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize7.4
```

Now `phpize -v` outputs:

```
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20190902
Zend Module Api No:      20190902
Zend Extension Api No:   320190902
```

Comment: Note to myself: I also had to update php-config to php-config7.4

Answer (score 4):

To show all installed phpize versions **installed using conformant packages on a debian-like system**:

```bash
sudo update-alternatives --config phpize
```

You will see list of phpize versions

```
root@my-server:~# sudo update-alternatives --config phpize
There are 3 choices for the alternative phpize (providing /usr/bin/phpize).

  Selection    Path                     Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/phpize.default   100       auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/phpize.default   100       manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/phpize8.1        81        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/phpize8.2        82        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Hit required number.

**PS:** You have to install `phpize` for the different versions of PHP for it to appear above. To install for PHP 8.1 run `sudo apt-get install php8.1-dev`

Answer (score 0):

You also might need to change `./configure` version :

```
phpize8.1
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config8.1 [...]
```

---

Context:

I had to compile a php module for php8.1 while I had many php version installed (8.0, 8.1, 8.2). So my main version was 8.2 and the module was not compiled correctly (for 8.2 instead of 8.1).
Anyway, this does not answer author question, but it might help some people who met the same issue and are in the same case as me.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.  Can you explain?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Also, if this is an addition to the other answer, consider an edit there.

Comment: This seems to be the start of an instruction to compile phpize from scratch, which isn't even remotely what the question asked about.

Comment: I had to compile a php module myself. So I met the same problem as the author.
In addition to set a version to `phpize`, I also had to set a version to next step of building my module : set a version to `php-config` in the `configure` command.
This does not answer author question, but it might help some people who met the same issue in the same case as me.